# Use of undefined constant DB_USER - assumed 'DB_USER'

Tags: php, mysql, javascript, jquery

**I get this error when I try to submit data.**
[image: Error]

**This is the code in db_config.php**
[image: Code]

**This is the original page from where am submitting the data (index.php)**
[image]

**What do you think am missing?** Emphasis on the ports maybe

Comment: This should be on SO but it's an easy error.

Comment: Please note that programming questions belong on [so]. For more information on Super User's scope, see the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the official [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) you need to use quotes to define the constants.

So instead of `define(DB_USER, "something")` it should be `define("DB_USER", "something")`.

Comment: That has removed the error but for some reason, its not bring back the data. 

Am supposed to be viewing the data in the DB on the **index page**

I have failed to attach the code of index.php

Comment: Well that would depend on what you do in your index page. From what you have posted you should now have a successful database connection. You would still need to write code to query that database and would need to fill it with some data if it doesn't contain any. On a side note you can mark code blocks using a four space indention or backticks.

Comment: Am trying to work on this [link] (http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/simple-php-jquery-ajax-crudinsert-update-delete-tutorial-example-with-source-codeexample.html) But it failing... Particularly on the part of displaying the data. Both After creating the item and on the index page

Comment: I'm really not sure what step you're on but you need to complete step three and four in order to get anything displayed. The index file in that case is entirely dumb. The data is read by the API from the database and displayed on the page by the javascript.

Comment: I have actually implemented all the files... Both the getData.php and the JavaScript are there

Comment: You probably should post this as an independent problem as it's likely a separate problem. To get some more information you could/should check whenever `error_reporting` is to display errors. It might be that the connection failes, the JSON is malformed or a number of other things. If you post it as an independent question, reference the tutorial and include your own code that is non trivial.