# Use of undefined constant DB_USER (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been getting these errors recently after updating to PHP 7.2:

```
[31-Aug-2018 08:46:02 UTC] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant DB_USER - assumed 'DB_USER' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/_userid_/domains/_domain_/public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 404
[31-Aug-2018 08:46:02 UTC] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant DB_PASSWORD - assumed 'DB_PASSWORD' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/_userid_/domains/_domain_/public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 404
[31-Aug-2018 08:46:02 UTC] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant DB_NAME - assumed 'DB_NAME' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/_userid_/domains/_domain_/public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 404
[31-Aug-2018 08:46:02 UTC] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant DB_HOST - assumed 'DB_HOST' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/_userid_/domains/_domain_/public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 404
```

Line 404 shows the following code:

```
$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST );
```

WordPress sets the constants like this:

```
define('DB_USER', 'someuserhere');
```

Help?

Line 404 can't be edit because it's part of WordPress, so when changed it's probably going to break the system. Also constants are meant to be called without quotes, right?

Comment: try this `$wpdb = new wpdb( 'DB_USER','DB_PASSWORD', 'DB_NAME', 'DB_HOST' );`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of undefined constant DB\_USER - assumed 'DB\_USER'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661111/use-of-undefined-constant-db-user-assumed-db-user)

Comment: @BhargavChudasama this is WordPress code, something I should not touch.

Comment: @BilalAhmed that is other code and not mine btw.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling WordPress? What version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: @magenta I have not to be honest, but the code in the original download is the same. I'm using the latest version btw.

Comment: In a correct installation where the define('DB_USER', 'someuserhere'); is in the file wp-config.php and the file wp-config.php is the WordPress root directory this error should not occur when the WordPress site is accessed through its usual URLs. What URL are you using to access WordPress when you get this error?

Comment: @magenta the errors show in my log, so there is no way of finding out what URL is accessed. I have just tried accessing /wp-includes/load.php but this doesn't give an error. The same goes for /wp-config.php. I would expect WP to have this handled.

Comment: First, neither /wp-includes/load.php nor wp-config.php should be loaded directly by a URL. They are supposed to be included. Is your side working for the standard WordPress URLS, e.g. .../wp-login.php, .../wp-admin.php, .../index.php, ... The standard WordPress URLs will include wp-config.php before using the database. If you have a custom URL then it the responsibility of your code to include wp-config.php.

Comment: @magenta I know, but I thought of testing it to see of someone is messing with the sites, but that is probably not the case. Sites are working perfectly otherwise.

Comment: Your question as written is very misleading. You should edit your question to indicate that your site works when accessed by WordPress's standard URLs. This error is the result of accessing your site by a custom URL that is failing to include wp-config.php. But, the way your question is written the reader thinks something is wrong with  the define since the reader does not know the site is actually working with the standard WordPress URLs.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the WordPress autoloader loading a core, plugin, or theme PHP file while bypassing the normal request pipeline (the part that loads `wp-config.php` where these constants are typically `define(...)`'d).

This can happen when a plugin is invoked and attempts to unconditionally access one of the database variables (e.g. `DB_USER`, `DB_HOST`, etc.) but the request is *not* a valid WordPress page/post/whatever request and the request pipeline has not been established. This can often be triggered by script kiddies or bots flooding your site with requests checking for known vulnerabilities or any weaknesses; if WordPress is not sanitizing all requests before the autoloader loads a plugin *or if the plugin is explicitly requesting that it be loaded before the request pipeline has been established* then this error may occur.

Install the php xdebug extension from pecl; in its default configuration it'll enhance your PHP error log to include the stack trace for these warnings and you can find out what plugin is being invoked that isn't doing these safety checks. (In my case, it was the DB query monitor plugin.)

Answer (score -2):

Try Like this:

> Instead of define(DB_USER, "something") it should be define("DB_USER", "something") in your wordpress file

Comment: Like I said, it defined by WordPress like this: define('DB_USER', 'someuserhere');

Comment: correct but you can change as php suggest constant should be in quotes. see below link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: single or double quotes does it matter?